# this.a() vs a.call(this) in javascript

Tags: javascript

1. `this.a()`
2. `a.call(this)`

As I understand:

- In both cases the *context* will be `this`.
- The first option can only be used when `a()` is a method of `this`.
- When searching the codebase, two options of calling the same thing makes things more complex.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Any other difference?
What are your best practices when using these two options?

Comment: *Anything else?* - What exactly you expect in the answer?

Comment: Please notice that `this.a.call(this)` == `this.a()` != `a.call(this)` != `a()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `a.call(this)` when you can do `this.a()`, it makes things harder to understand and AFAIK you don't gain anything by doing this...

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) are useful when you want to use a method from another "class" but with your `this` parameter, such as:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a') ;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, callback) ;
```

You can't use `nodes.forEach` because `nodes` is a `NodeList` not an `Array` and thus do not have a `forEach` method, but you can do the above.

Another use of `call` is when you want to force the `this` instance on a callback method (e.g. when you are creating a plugin).

```
plugin.doSomething ('#id', function () {
    // I would like 'this' to reference my HTMLElement here
}) ;
```

So in `doSomething` you could do something like:

```
function doSomething (selector, callback) {
    var e = document.querySelector (selector) ;
    // Whatever... 
    callback.call(e) ;
}
```

Comment: There is also one case for `apply` to work with unknown number of arguments. Like `arr=[1,2,3,4]; maximum = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);`

Comment: A problem that may occurs when using this.a() is that when using the module pattern - you must add a() to the return object of the module, which force you to expose a() outside your module.

Answer (score 0):

One is calling a method `a` on `this` while the other is calling the function `a` and passing a context of `this`.

...really not that similar. Let me show:

```
(function(){
    function a() {
        alert('global a');
    }

    function b()
    {
        this.a = function() {
            alert('scope of b() method a');
        }

        this.a(); // alerts 'scope of b() method a'
        a.call(this) // alerts 'global a'
    }

    b();
})();
```

See, not even necessarily calling the same function. So there's definitely some decent differences between the two concepts. Far from identical.

IWithout the IIFE surrounding it and NOT in strict mode those would call the same function simply because `this` would default to global...and in strict mode, with or without the IIFE, the `this.a();` would not only not call the same function, it would throw an error since the default value of `this` would be undefined. In fact...in strict mode the situations where those two lines would even call the same function at all would be pretty limited.

As far as the question of "which should I use"...well, that depends on what you're trying to do, since they do different things! The fact that those two concepts **can** overlap in the right situation does not change that.

1) The `this` keyword is basically the context of the execution of a function, or refers to the instantiated object when a function is called with the `new` keyword. If you're trying to reference a function expression on the execution context of where your function was called from, or trying to reference the instance of an object made with `new` within that class definition (i.e. you're doing JS class properties/methods) then you'd use `this.a();` to reference that.

2) If you're trying to reference the `a` function within the current scope but force it to run with the context of whatever `this` is from where the function is being executed then you'd use `a.call(this);`

3) More likely, if you're just calling a function in the current scope and don't need to influence its `this` keyword context you'd quite simply use `a();`

Answer (score -2):

Yes, both cases are identical. And nobody uses `call` or `apply` when you have object and you need to call its method. Mostly developers use them when you need substitute the context. 
One of common cases is to convert an arguments object into an array:

```
function fn() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(args);
}
```

Comment: Considering in many cases `this.a();` will throw an error when `a.call(this);` won't I'm a bit skeptical of calling them *"identical"*. One is calling a method ON `this`, while the other is calling the function a (not on `this`) and passing `this` as context.

Comment: What is an example of a case when one throws an error and another does not ?

Comment: Literally just make a `function a(){}` and then try calling it with `this.a();` and `a.call(this);` The former will make an error, the latter will not. The function is simply not on `this`. `this.a()` is looking for a method `a` on the object `this`.

Comment: ^ I should point out that I mean for that example to be wrapped in an IIFE. I hardly even think in non-IIFE context anymore...and the the same will happen in strict mode (with or without the IIFE) since `this` will be undefined.